# Stream type with monadic effects

Tags: functional-programming, stream, monads, idris

Is there a standard type (especially in the stdlib) for a `Stream` type (by which I mean a potentially infinite, lazy sequence) which allows for effects when accessing the next element? Something like this pseudocode (for monad `m`, element type `a`)

```
m (a, m (a, m (a, m (a, ...
```

I tried modding `Stream` from the stdlib but kept getting

```
Error: StreamM is not total, not strictly positive
```

I'm having difficulty remembering the exact implementation, but here's one without the `Monad`

```
data StreamM : (Type -> Type) -> Type -> Type where
  (::) : a -> Inf (m (StreamM m a)) -> StreamM m a
```

Apparently it's because it can't be seen as total because for all we know `m` is not strictly positive. It works if I make `m` something specific like `State Nat`.

My knowledge of codata is minimal, and I don't know what polarity (positive etc.) means.

**Context**

I am producing a stream of uniquely-named values, where each value depends on all the previous values (and some other stuff). The monad `m` generates the names.

Comment: Please include your exact definition of `StreamM` that is giving this error message. Also, is this with Idris 1 or Idris 2?

Comment: @Cactus i've added a non-`Monad` version. I can't remember how I included the `Monad m`, but the error's the same with or without it.

Comment: @Cactus Idris 2